# Calling Snapshot from the command line (FastLane Tools > Snapshot)

Tags: ios, fastlane

I am using [Snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot) from the [FastLane](https://fastlane.tools/) suite.

For my purposes I am calling the various tools from scripts and pass in the appropriate environment variables I am using as the inputs. I am having trouble passing in the `devices` parameter as well as the `languages` parameter.

Example:

```
snapshot \
--workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace" \
--scheme "MyScheme" \
--output_directory "MyOutputDirectory" \
--clear_previous_screenshots \
--stop_after_first_error \
--devices (['iPhone 4s', 'iPhone 5', 'iPhone 6', 'iPhone 6 Plus'])
```

The above results in an error when setting `devices` parameter.

**How do I pass these arrays to this tool?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass the devices / languages to `snapshot` using the command line. Instead add the languages and devices to your `Snapfile` or `Fastfile`

Comment: Thank you creator @KrauseFx!

Answer (score 0):

> I know its too late but I want to add here that you can pass devices from command line in following way

> add option to your lane which you gonna access from commandLine

```
lane :screenshots do |options|
     capture_screenshots(scheme:"QuickgetUITests",devices:options[:devices]) 
end
```

> then pass argument like below from command line

```
fastlane screenshots devices:"iPhone 8"
```

Note: You can Pass Other Options as well same way such like languages